# How can I make a "fake" subsection number?

Tags: sectioning, formatting, numbering, examples

I'm writing a LaTeX document which includes examples of how to structure another LaTeX document. However, I can't figure out a way to make it so that there's a subsection in the example that is a) not included in the table of contents and b) has a number that DOES NOT increment with the main sections.

`\include` and `\input` both increment, so I can't use them.

Here's my current MWE using two files and `\include`:

```
\fbox{
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}

\include{EX1}

\end{minipage}
}
```

EX1:

```
\subsection{Fake Subsection}

Some text.
```

[image: Attempt to make a fake subsection:]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! That's by far no MWE ;-)

Comment: Brain fart! I meant "attempt".

Comment: `\include` does introduce a new page everytime, I assume you don't want that really!

Comment: Please have a look on another possible solution at the end of my answer!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Define an environment within which counter stepping and ToC-writing is disabled. This allows great freedom:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\newcounter{savesection}
\newcounter{savesubsection}
\newcounter{savesubsubsection}
\newenvironment{quietsections}
  {% Store sectional counters
   \setcounter{savesection}{\value{section}}%
   \setcounter{savesubsection}{\value{subsection}}%
   \setcounter{savesubsubsection}{\value{subsubsection}}%
   \renewcommand{\refstepcounter}[1]{}% Remove \refstepcounter functionality
   \renewcommand{\addcontentsline}[3]{}% Remove \addcontentslie functionality
  }{%
   % Restore sectional counters
   \setcounter{section}{\value{savesection}}%
   \setcounter{subsection}{\value{savesubsection}}%
   \setcounter{subsubsection}{\value{savesubsubsection}}%
  }

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{A section}
\section*{Another section}

\bigskip

\noindent
\fbox{%
  \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}
    \begin{quietsections}
      \setcounter{section}{4}
      \section{A fake section}
      \setcounter{subsection}{3}
      \subsection{Another fake subsection}
      \subsection*{More subsections}
    \end{quietsections}
  \end{minipage}%
}

\bigskip

\section{Yet another section}

\end{document}
```

Counters for sectional headings are stored at `\begin{quietsections}`, and restored during `\end{quietsections}`.

---

The following shows how it can be done for `\section`, but it is easy to extend it to other sectional units:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\fakesection}{s m o m}{{%
  \renewcommand{\refstepcounter}[1]{}% Remove functionality of \refstepcounter
  \renewcommand{\addcontentsline}[3]{}% Remove functionality of \addcontentsline
  \renewcommand{\thesection}{#2}% Set subsection counter
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\section*{#4}}
    {\IfValueTF{#3}
       {\section[#3]{#4}}
       {\section{#4}}%
    }
}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{A section}
\section*{Another section}

\bigskip

\noindent
\fbox{%
  \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}
    \fakesection{5}{A fake section}
    \fakesection*{X}{Another fake section}
  \end{minipage}%
}

\bigskip

\section{Yet another section}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Seems I was a bit late.

Comment: This allows subsubsections as well, which should be useful to me! Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

**UPDATE** at the end, with automatic restoration of arbitrary counters!!!!

Use a `dummycounter` that resets with the upper section level and `\let\c@subsection\c@dummycounter`, i.e. explicitly use the count register `c@dummycounter` instead of `c@subsection`

If this is used inside of the minipage, the `\let` operation does not leak outside (since `minipage` is an environment and as such a group).

Please note, that my approach won't be useful for `\subsubsection` out of the box then. This requires more work!

Setting the `tocdepth` counter appropiately will prevent the appearance of the fake subsection in the `ToC`!

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{dummycounter}[section]%
\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\example}[1]{%
  \fbox{%
   \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
     \addtocontents{toc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{-2}}
     \let\c@subsection\c@dummycounter%

      #1

    \end{minipage}
    \addtocontents{toc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}}
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Foo}
\subsection{Real subsection}


\example{\subsection{Fake subsection}\blindtext}

\subsection{Another real subsection}

\section{Other foo}

\subsection{Real subsection}


\example{\subsection{Fake subsection}\blindtext}

\example{\subsection{Fake subsection}\blindtext}

\subsection{Real subsection}

\subsection{Real subsection}



\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update**

An `xassoccnt` version with `\BackupCounterValues` -- This maintains the  values of various counters and automatically prevents entries to the `ToC`, `Lof` and `Lot`.

A future version of `xassoccnt` will support such features out of the box -- I have put it on my to-do-list!

Using `figure` and `table` won't work, due to the boxing!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{xassoccnt}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{hyperref}


\newcounter{storedtocdepth}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand{\preventcft}[1][toc,lof,lot]{%
  \clist_set:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {#1}%
  \clist_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {%
    \addtocontents{##1}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{-2}}%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\restorecft}[1][toc,lof,lot]{%
  \clist_set:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {#1}%
  \clist_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {%
    \addtocontents{##1}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{\number\value{storedtocdepth}}}%
  }%
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentCommand{\example}{O{resetbackup=true}+m}{%
  \BackupCounterValues[#1]{subsection,subsubsection,figure,table}%
  \CopyDocumentCounters{tocdepth}{storedtocdepth}%
  \begin{tcolorbox}[code={\preventcft}]%
    #2%
  \end{tcolorbox}%
  \RestoreAllCounterValues
  \restorecft%
}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\section{Foo}
\subsection{Real subsection}


\begin{figure}
  \begin{center}
    \caption{A beautiful duck outside}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{ente}
  \end{center}
\end{figure}
\example{\subsection{Fake subsection}
  \begin{center}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{ente}%
  \captionof{figure}{A beautiful duck}
  \end{center}
  \blindtext
}

\subsection{Another real subsection}



\section{Other foo}



\example{\subsection{Fake subsection}\blindtext}

\subsection{Another real subsection of 2nd section}

\subsubsection{Foo subsubsection}
\example{
\subsection{Fake subsection}\blindtext

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{*{5}{l}}
\hline
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{An internal tabular}
\end{center}

\subsubsection{Fake subsubsection}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{*{5}{l}}
\hline
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{Another internal tabular}
\end{center}



\subsubsection{Another fake subsubsection}\subsubsection{Imaginary subsubsection}}


\subsubsection{Real world subsubsection}
\subsection{Yet another real subsection of 2nd section}


\subsection{more real subsections}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Actually, this is a job for `xassoccnt` and `BackupCounterValues`